# Overwhelmed by Linux

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I really love Linux, and have gone through RHCSA and have a solid foundations over the concepts. But my problem is that i tend to forget some commands after some time, despite i'm really sure i completely understood and used to to do very easily when i first studied them.
This did not happen with me when i was studying Windows Server or Power-Shell.
Is it normal to forget some easy\basic stuff like that? or did someone experience the same when they started in Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 20 years of linux and BSD, I am not ashamed to admit that I have to google the basics from time to time, and read the `ls` manpage. This comes with the territory.

Frequent use is what results in memorizing the commands and their most useful switches. With time you'll learn them by heart, especially if you start combining them through pipes.

Some things are easier to memorize. For example, working with `tar` and `rsync` can seem very complex at first, but after a while you remember the switches you normally use, as they're used pretty often, and at that point it's pretty easy. On the flipside, there are those things you do only a few times such as setting up a dns server, which is something I have to look up every time I need to do so.

Comment: man pages are great

Comment: History is good too. Also self-written cheat sheets and script collections.

Comment: You can [set your environment up](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/) so that your history shows date & time, and then if you remember roughly when you did something, you can easily find it again.

Answer (score 3):

If you google "linux cheat sheet" you'll get about a gazillion results. This means you're in good company!

Dowload one of your liking, print it out and put it in a handy place.

Comment: I make wallpaper with cheat sheets.